# Yosemite 10.10.05 - Distorted text and toolbar in application?

Tags: macos, font

When trying to run the [bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) web designer application(ver 1.7.2), on a Macbook Air running Yosemite 10.10.05, text and some menus appear distorted and almost unreadable. We've tried restoring the system fonts to default using font book and changing the display resolution and nothing seems to work. This application runs fine on a 2014 Macbook Pro 15inch running the exact same OS. Puzzled as to what is causing this.

[image]

Comment: Looks more like gpu caused artifacts, not from font..

Comment: Why only on this application? Everything else looks fine.

Comment: I still got artifacts like this only on Android studio (On mac mini at work.. and it has intel hd) and sometimes when i move mouse, it dissapears and appears multiple times.. I don't know what causes this, but are not always present... it appears sometimes